# Removing a tick mark made using Pen in a scanned pdf

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have a PDF file with Multiple choise questions . The answered are marked . I would like to remove the "tick"portion of it without majorly altering the sheet . I would like to automate it for the entire PDF .In the images below , would like to remove the "tick" mark alone . My input file is a PDF . For sake of representation have give a image .
Note . I use GNU/Linux
[[image: Question paper with answer marked][1]]

Comment: that's a scan of a piece of paper. it being in PDF format won't matter because the scan is a raster graphic anyway. that's why I've removed the PDF tag.

Comment: please review [ask]. present your "research" into solving the task.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference that I can see between the checkmark and the rest of the image is the thickness of the black line. Thus we can replace the thicker black line with a sample of the background of your image

Here is a way to do this using Python/OpenCV/Numpy:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#load the image
img = cv2.imread("pen_mark.png")

#Threshold the image to a 2-channel black and white image with the text as white and the background as black.
black_and_white = (img < 128).astype(np.uint8) * 255

#erode the thin lines, leaving only the thicker pen-drawn checkmark.
checkmark = cv2.morphologyEx(black_and_white, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, np.ones((5,5)))
#dilate the remaining checkmark back to slightly larger than its original size
checkmark = cv2.morphologyEx(checkmark, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((7,7)))

#switch the left and right side of the original image in order to get a sample of the
#original speckled background overlaying the position of the checkmark.
rolled_img = np.roll(img, shift=img.shape[1]//2)

#replace the pixels of the original checkmark with the background
img[checkmark.nonzero()] = rolled_img[checkmark.nonzero()]

#save the new image
cv2.imwrite("result.png", img)
```

[image]

Note that this probably won't be a reliable solution for all of your PDFs. I assume the thickness of the pen mark will change. There will probably also be cases where the pen mark overlaps other lines and you'll end up with blank spots. Another problem is the difficulty in setting the background so that it blends nicely with its surroundings.

Comment: On second thought, flipping the image might be better than rolling it in order to get a background sample. You can replace the roll line with: flipped_image = np.fliplr(img)

Comment: Give me little time , let me check it and get back to you